# shinydashboad: submenuitem in conditionalpanel disappears

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am loading users and corresponding roles from a database. For certain roles I want the second `menuItem` to disappear and I am using a `conditionalPanel` for that which works fine. The problem is that also for users with the right roles the second `menuItem` shows after loading the app but disappears as soon as a `menuItem` above is unfolded. And it does not come back.

Am I doing this the right way?

```
# global ------------------------------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)


# header ------------------------------------------------------------------

header <- dashboardHeader(
  titleWidth = "300px",
  title = "Menuitem disappears"
)



# sidebar -----------------------------------------------------------------

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  disable = FALSE,
  collapsed = FALSE,
  width = "300px",
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "menu1",
    menuItem(
      "Menu Item 1", 
      menuSubItem("Submenu Item 1", tabName = "tab_1"),
      menuSubItem("Submenu Item 2", tabName = "tab_2"),
      tabName = "tab_3"
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "output.performance",
      
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(
          "Menu Item 2", 
          menuSubItem("Submenu Item 1", tabName = "tab_5"),
          tabName = "tab_4"
        )
      )
    )
    
  ),
  
  hr(), 
  
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "myinput",
    label = "Example Input",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
    inline = FALSE,
    width = "100%",
    options = list(showTick = FALSE),
  )
)



# body --------------------------------------------------------------------

body <- dashboardBody(
  "Text goes here"
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "black", title = "Reprex")



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  user <- reactive({
    "example user"
  })
   
  user_roles <- reactive({
    "Boss"
  })
  
  output$performance <- reactive({
    any(c("Boss") %in% user_roles())
  })
  outputOptions(output, "performance", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
}  



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I think the right way to do it is using `renderMenu`:

```
# global ------------------------------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)


# header ------------------------------------------------------------------

header <- dashboardHeader(
  titleWidth = "300px",
  title = "Menuitem disappears"
)



# sidebar -----------------------------------------------------------------

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  disable = FALSE,
  collapsed = FALSE,
  width = "300px",
  
  sidebarMenuOutput("myMenu"),

  hr(), ## TMP
  
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "myinput",
    label = "Example Input",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
    inline = FALSE,
    width = "100%",
    options = list(showTick = FALSE),
  )
)



# body --------------------------------------------------------------------

body <- dashboardBody(
  "Text goes here"
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "black", title = "Reprex")



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  user <- reactive({
    "example user"
  })
   
  user_roles <- reactive({
    "Boss"
  })
  
  output$myMenu <- renderMenu({
    menu_list <- list(
      menuItem(
        "Menu Item 1", 
        menuSubItem("Submenu Item 1", tabName = "tab_1"),
        menuSubItem("Submenu Item 2", tabName = "tab_2"),
        tabName = "tab_3"
      )
    )
    if (any(c("Boss") %in% user_roles())) {
      menu_list <- append(
        menu_list,
        list(
          menuItem(
            "Menu Item 2", 
            menuSubItem("Submenu Item 1", tabName = "tab_5"),
            tabName = "tab_4"
          )
        )
      )
    }
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "menu1",
      .list = menu_list
    )
  }) 
}  



shinyApp(ui, server)
```